# Installing lxde offline Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: lxde, offline

I need to install lxde (only vanilla one)  in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit system. It has no internet access so I have to download lxde and install it offline. How do I do it. Since typing 
sudo apt-get install lxde wouldn't work.